# Как вызов функции передать в качестве параметра JS и как не вызывать определенные функции на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
    function checkPage(obj) {
        console.log("start checkPage");
        if (typeof obj === 'object'){
            for (var key in obj) {
                if ($('body').hasClass(key)){
                    if (obj[key].isArray){
                        for (var i=0;i<obj[key].length;i++){
                            obj[key][i];
                        }
                    }else {
                        obj[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function indexFunc() {
        console.log('index')
    }
    function newsFunc() {
        console.log('news')
    }
    checkPage({
            index: [indexFunc()],
            news: [newsFunc()],
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class='index'></body>
```

Подключаю к обеим страницам сайта один и тот же `script.min.js`.
На странице, для которой изначально разрабатывался `script.min.js` все работает штатно, но на второй странице

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки, которые отключают вообще скрипты. Я выяснил что ошибки вызывают функции, которые не используются на этой странице. И придумал сделать функцию, которая бы проверяла что за страница и вызывала бы нужные функции. Но у меня не вышло, функции вызываются еще на этапе объвления их как параметров. См. пример.
У меня два вопроса. Как исправить ошибки, что у меня на странице, т.е. не вызывать  определенные функции. И если это не связано с тем решением, что я попытался реализовать, хотелось бы знать, можно ли передать функцию в другую функцию, чтобы ее там выполнить?

Comment: предоставленный код никак не относится к получаемым ошибкам.

Comment: Понятное дело. Ошибки возникают в функциях которые вызываются при загрузке. Но на данной странице эти функции не нужны, и их так много, что проще придумать способ их не вызывать, чем разбираться почему в данном случае они не работают

Comment: Ошибки очевидны: идет обращение к элементам, которых нет на странице. Если предоставленный код не относится к получаемым ошибкам, зачем он был добавлен в вопрос?